# Axios Post call getting 502 proxy error in production where as request is server is happening and success response

Tags: reactjs, axios

Can anyone help, as I couldn't recreate this issue to check why this is happening.
I was using axios for calling rest api in my react application, I couldn't find any issue while developing and in uat , but when the code went live , in production always axios one post call is getting 502 proxy error but the same request was made to rest service and in backend everything is success. So , backend is success but user is seeing unsuccess page as it is getting 502 error.

Everything network and load balancers couldn't find any issue.

Example Code

```
this.postapi().then(function (response) {
  //doing something
  });
  postapi() {
    return axios.post('/postapi', {
      // request data
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
      if(error.response.status === 500 ){
        //error page redirect 
      }else{
        //unsuccess page redirect
      }
  });
}
```

from above code, always the API call is being done and success in rest service, but getting 502 proxy error and going to catch block and showing unsuccess page

This behavior is only happening in production

Environment:

> Axios Version [e.g. 0.19.0]
>   Browser [e.g. Chrome, Safari]
>   React 16.9.0